# Any DAL/ORM on GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, orm, rdbms, data-access-layer

Is there any Database Abstraction Layer (DAL) or Object Relational Mapper (ORM) that works on Google App Engine (GAE), and on normal relational databases (RDBS), other  than [web2py](http://www.web2py.com)'s?

If not, is anybody working on porting one of the existing DAL/ORM to GAE?

Answer (score 4):

There is an ORM for Google App Engine. There are some differences between it and SQLAlchemy, but looks like it works. Check this page: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entitiesandmodels.html

Answer (score 2):

Web2Py has a DAL that is compatible to GAE. In fact, the whole framework can be deployed to GAE: http://mdp.cti.depaul.edu/examples/default/index

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it looks like SQLAlchemy is working on it, but it's incomplete / unfinished.  Good luck!